# Implementing first fit like algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, job-scheduling

Problem:
I have 3 machines, each machine have a limit of 30 ms time, each machine have 3 zones that a task can't be executed there. 
The tasks have a P (priority) and W (weight, which is the time to complete the task in this setup), tasks must be first ordered by a priority, from lower to higher like this:

Task 01 {6, 2} // P/W = 3 this task executed last (3)

Task 02 {7, 7} // P/W = 1 this task executed first (1)

Task 03 {4, 2} // P/W = 2 this task executed second (2)

Now, in order to execute a tasks(I have 6), I must check all 3 machines to find the first fit to the task, to chose a fit for task, it must be the optimal in the 3 machines, example:

Machine 01; |-----5----9-------16-17--19-20|

Machine 02: |----4-5--7-8---------17-18--|

Machine 03: |-----5---8--10---13--15---18--|

(1)Task 02 executed in machine 02 (We look for P ms to execute task, and the minimum time to start a task, since both machine 01 (starting from 9 ms) and 02 (starting from 8 ms) have a 7 ms free time, machine 02 can start a task first then the machine 01).

(2)Task 03 executed in machine 02 (We look for P ms to execute task).

(3)Task 01 executed in machine 01 (We look for P ms to execute task).

Certain periods of time are defined as critical, and cannot be used to schedule a job. These periods (for instance 5-9, 7-8), are stored in the dedicated struct `z_indispo`.

The `bfeet` struct is used to store in witch the task start and in witch machine.

I implemented mostly the entire algorithm in C, but my results are different than expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _z_indispo {
    int t1;
    int t2;
} z_indispo; 

typedef struct _machines {
    int t[20]; // array represent time
    z_indispo zone[2];
} machines;

typedef struct _tache {
    int p;
    int w;
    int c; //  p/w
    int i; // Task number
} tache;

typedef struct _bfeet {
    int t; // Store the time to of ending execution by a task
    int m; // The machine responsible for executing a task.
} bfeet;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    machines m[4];
    tache j[6];
    tache j_tmp;
    bfeet b[4];
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int u = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int trouver = 0;
    int f_totale = 0;
    int f[3] = {0};

    m[0].zone[0].t1 = 7;
    m[0].zone[0].t2 = 9;
    m[0].zone[1].t1 = 14;
    m[0].zone[1].t2 = 15;

    m[1].zone[0].t1 = 8;
    m[1].zone[0].t2 = 9;
    m[1].zone[1].t1 = 16;
    m[1].zone[1].t2 = 17;

    m[2].zone[0].t1 = 7;
    m[2].zone[0].t2 = 8;
    m[2].zone[1].t1 = 18;
    m[2].zone[1].t2 = 19;



    /*
     * Initialise all machines
     *   0: Represent free time.
     *  -1: Represent critical zone range.
     *  -2: Represent a task already executed. 
     */
    for(i = 0; i< 3; ++i)
    {
        for(count = 0; count < 20; ++count)
        {
            if((count >= m[i].zone[0].t1 - 1 && count <= m[i].zone[0].t2 - 1) || 
               (count >= m[i].zone[1].t1 - 1 && count <= m[i].zone[1].t2 - 1))
            {
                m[i].t[count] = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                m[i].t[count] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i< 3; ++i)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            printf("   D(1,1)           t1    s1  D(1,2)     t2 s2  D(1,3)\n");
        else if(i == 1)
            printf("   D(2,1)              t1 s1  D(2,2)           t2 s2  D(2,3)\n");
        else if(i == 2)
            printf("   D(3,1)           t1 s1  D(3,2)                    t2 s2  D(3,3)\n");
        printf("|");
        for(count = 0; count < 20; ++count)
        {
                printf("%3d", m[i].t[count]);

        }

        printf(" |\n\n");
    }

    j[0].p = 5;
    j[0].w = 2;
    j[0].i = 1;

    j[1].p = 9;
    j[1].w = 3;
    j[1].i = 2;

    j[2].p = 6;
    j[2].w = 3;
    j[2].i = 3;

    j[3].p = 6;
    j[3].w = 4;
    j[3].i = 4;

    j[4].p = 7;
    j[4].w = 7;
    j[4].i = 5;

    /*
     * Calc C = P/W .
    */
    for(count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
    {
        j[count].c = j[count].p / j[count].w;
    }

    /*
     * Sort tasks from low to hight
     */
    for(count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
    {
        for(k = 0; k < 5 - count; ++k)
        {
            if(j[k].c > j[k + 1].c)
            {
                j_tmp = j[k + 1];
                j[k + 1] = j[k];
                j[k] = j_tmp;
            }
        }
    }


    /*printf("|%2J  |%2   P  |%2  W  | C  |\n");
    printf("_____________________\n");
    for(count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
    {
        printf("|%-4d|%-4d|%-4d|%-4d|\n", j[count].i, j[count].p, j[count].w, j[count].c);
    }

    printf("\n");*/

    /*
     * Execute tasks
     */
    while(n < 5) 
    {
        for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count)
        {
            i = 0;
            trouver = 0;
            while(i <= 20 && trouver != 1)
            {
                if(m[count].t[i] == 0) // We have a  free time to start with it.
                {
                    u = 0; // num of available indexs.
                    while(m[count].t[i] != -1 && m[count].t[i] != -2)
                    {
                        if(u == j[n].p)
                            break;

                        ++u;
                        ++i;
                    }

                    if(u < j[n].p)
                    {
                        while(m[count].t[i] == -1 && m[count].t[i] == -2) // bypass unfree unites
                            ++i;
                    }
                    else if(u == j[n].p)
                    {   
                        b[count].t = i - u;
                        b[count].m = count; // 
                        trouver = 1; // we find the Necessary unites to start a task
                    }
                }
                else
                    ++i;
            }
        }

        if(u < j[n].p)
            printf("There is no free time to execute task %d", j[n].i);
        else
        {
            // Find the minimum time in all machines to start a task
            b[3].t = b[0].t;
            b[3].m = b[0].m;
            for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count)
            {
                if(b[3].t > b[count + 1].t)
                {
                    b[3].t = b[count + 1].t;
                    b[3].m = b[count + 1].m;
                }
            }

            // Put -2 to indicate that index is unfree
            u = b[3].t + j[n].p;
            for(count = b[3].t; count < u; ++count)
            {
                m[b[3].m].t[count] = -2;
            }

            if(b[3].m == 0)
                f[0] = (b[3].t + j[n].p);
            else if(b[3].m == 1)
                f[1] = (b[3].t + j[n].p);
            else if(b[3].m == 2)
                f[2] = (b[3].t + j[n].p);

            printf("Task %d end at %-2d, machine %d.\n", j[n].i, b[3].t + j[n].p, b[3].m + 1);
        }
        ++n;
    }  

    printf("\n"); 
    f_totale = f[0] + f[1] + f[2];
    printf("F of machine 01: %d.\n", f[0]); 
    printf("F of machine 02: %d.\n", f[1]); 
    printf("F of machine 03: %d.\n", f[2]); 
    printf("Total F: %d.\n", f_totale); 
    printf("\n"); 
    /*printf("\n"); 
    for(i = 0; i< 3; ++i)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            printf("   D(1,1)           t1    s1  D(1,2)     t2 s2  D(1,3)\n");
        else if(i == 1)
            printf("   D(2,1)              t1 s1  D(2,2)           t2 s2  D(2,3)\n");
        else if(i == 2)
            printf("   D(3,1)           t1 s1  D(3,2)                    t2 s2  D(3,3)\n");
        printf("|");
        for(count = 0; count < 20; ++count)
        {
                printf("%3d", m[i].t[count]);

        }

        printf(" |\n\n");
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have now only two unavailability zones in each machine. I also updated the code to fix some errors, but I still get a different output then this example:
I have this unavailability zones:

```
m[0].zone[0].t1 = 7;
m[0].zone[0].t2 = 9;
m[0].zone[1].t1 = 14;
m[0].zone[1].t2 = 15;

m[1].zone[0].t1 = 8;
m[1].zone[0].t2 = 9;
m[1].zone[1].t1 = 16;
m[1].zone[1].t2 = 17;

m[2].zone[0].t1 = 7;
m[2].zone[0].t2 = 8;
m[2].zone[1].t1 = 18;
m[2].zone[1].t2 = 19;
```

5 tasks:

```
p | 6 9 5 7 6
w | 3 3 2 7 4 
_______________
c | 2 3 2 1 1
```

After ordering by `c`:

```
p | 7 6 5 6 9
w | 7 4 2 3 3 
_______________
c | 1 1 2 2 3
```

The execution of tasks should be like this:

```
      J4                              
|_______7__9_____14_15__________| ms
```

Task 04 should end at 7, P represent the time necessary to execute a task.

```
     J5                                                    
|________8_9__________16_17_____| ms
```

Task 05 should end at 7.

```
   J1        J3                                             
|_______7_8_______________18_19_| ms
```

Task 01 should end at 6, task 03 should end at 14.

**UPDATE 02:** (*This problem fixed*)

I noticed a strange behavior in my program, after I initializing m[i].t[count] array, I found that variables responsible for storing unavailability zones changed: 
NOTE: This problem fixed.

**UPDATE03:** (*This problem fixed but with new issue*)

I have situation when a task can't find the necessary unites to start, I never get this message "There is no free time to execute task ", witch I should receive it for task 2, since it has 9 unites, and all machines have no such of free time like that. The code responsible for this test:

```
    for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count) // search on all machines
    {
        i = 0;
        trouver = 0;
        while(i < 20 && trouver != 1)
        {
            if(m[count].t[i] == 0) // We have a  free time to start with it.
            {
                u = 0; // num of available indexs.
                while(m[count].t[i] != -1 && m[count].t[i] != -2)
                {
                    if(u == j[n].p)
                        break;

                    ++u;
                    ++i;
                }

                if(u < j[n].p)
                {
                    while(m[count].t[i] == -1 && m[count].t[i] == -2) // bypass unfree unites
                        ++i;
                }
                else if(u == j[n].p)
                {   
                    b[count].t = i - u;
                    b[count].m = count; // 
                    trouver = 1; // we find the Necessary unites to start a task
                }
            }
            else
                ++i;
        }
    }
    /* u represent the number of continuous free time, 
       j[n].p represent the necessary time to execute the current task, n is the current task 
    if(u < j[n].p) 
        printf("There is no free time to execute task %d", j[n].i);
    else
    {
        // Find the minimum time in all machines to start a task
        b[3].t = b[0].t;
        b[3].m = b[0].m;
```

**UPDATE04:**

Now I can see excluded task when there is no free time to execute a task, however, the output is not right, because I see a task override the period time on another task:

```
while(n < 5) 
{
    k = 0;
    for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count)
    {
        i = 0;
        u = 0;
        trouver = 0;
        while(i < 20 && trouver != 1)
        {
            if(m[count].t[i] == 0) // We have a  free time to start with it.
            {
                //u = 0; // num of available indexs.
                if(u == j[n].p)
                    break;
                else
                {       
                    ++u;
                    ++i;
                }
            }

        if(u != j[n].p)
        {
            if((m[count].t[i] == -1 || m[count].t[i] == -2))// bypass unfree unites
            {
                u = 0;
                ++i;
            }
        }

        if(u == j[n].p)
        {   
            ++k;
            b[count].t = i - u;
            b[count].m = count; // 
            trouver = 1; // we find the Necessary unites to start a task
        }
    }
}

if(u != j[n].p)
{
    printf("There is no free time to execute task %d.\n", j[n].i);
}
else
{
    // Find the minimum time in all machines to start a task
    b[3] = b[0];
    for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count)
    {
        if(b[count].t != 0)
            if(b[3].t > b[count + 1].t)
            {
                b[3] = b[count + 1];
            }
    }

    // Put -2 to indicate that index is unfree
    u = b[3].t + j[n].p;
    for(count = b[3].t; count < u; ++count)
    {
        m[b[3].m].t[count] = -2;
    }

    if(b[3].m == 0)
        f[0] = (b[3].t + j[n].p);
    else if(b[3].m == 1)
        f[1] = (b[3].t + j[n].p);
    else if(b[3].m == 2)
        f[2] = (b[3].t + j[n].p);

    printf("Task %d end at %-2d, machine %d.\n", j[n].i, b[3].t + j[n].p, b[3].m + 1);
}

++n;
```

}

**Output:**

```
   D(1,1)           t1    s1  D(1,2)     t2 s2  D(1,3)
|  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0 |

   D(2,1)              t1 s1  D(2,2)           t2 s2  D(2,3)
|  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0 |

   D(3,1)           t1 s1  D(3,2)                    t2 s2  D(3,3)
|  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0 |

| J  | P  | W  | C  |
_____________________
|1   |5   |2   |2   |
|2   |7   |3   |2   |
|3   |8   |3   |2   |
|5   |17  |7   |2   |
|4   |16  |4   |4   |

Task 1 end at 5 , machine 1.
Task 2 end at 7 , machine 1.
Task 3 end at 8 , machine 1.
There is no free time to execute task 5.
There is no free time to execute task 4.

F of machine 01: 8.
F of machine 02: 0.
F of machine 03: 0.
Total F: 8.


   D(1,1)           t1    s1  D(1,2)     t2 s2  D(1,3)
| -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -1  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0 |

   D(2,1)              t1 s1  D(2,2)           t2 s2  D(2,3)
|  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0 |

   D(3,1)           t1 s1  D(3,2)                    t2 s2  D(3,3)
|  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0 |
```

Comment: First, could you add comments to help understand the purpose of the variables? _tache_, and _bfeet_ especially. Also, in you `_machines` struct you have `int t[19];` but 20 is the max time (would be indexed 0-19), and `z_indispo zone[2];` but 3 actual critical zones  (as I deduct from you trying to initialize `m[1].zone[2]`)

Comment: Why is there a critical zone at 5-9 and 7-8 and what are the others?

Comment: apparently, the `_z_indispo` struct is used to store the critical zones (ie the periods of unavailability). From the algorithm standpoint, we only need to know they exist and are stored there, am I wrong?

Comment: @Phpdevpad Critical zones mean the task can't be executed in the range of theme.

Comment: @SIFE: Sure, but in first-fit we also start with 1 machine and not 3. I'm not sure what should be optimized?

Comment: @Phpdevpad In this algorithm I have to finish a task at the minimum amount of time.

Comment: What is the specific question here?  Is it that you don't know what the correct algorithm is?  Or is that you know the algorithm, but your implementation differs?  If it's the latter, then a debugger sounds like the first port of call.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, my implementation differs, beside that my skills in gdb is too poor, so, I am still with printf only to examine variable value.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth For the update 02, even with GDB I don't understand why I don't get the message "There is no free time to execute task ".

Comment: with the right syntactical constructs, the code in your update3 could be reduced to <20 lines, making errors easier to spot.

Comment: @wildplasser But I am still not get the warring message.

Comment: can you, for instance, guarantee that *inside the two inner loops on i*  `while(m[count].t[i] != -1 && m[count].t[i] != -2)` , `i` will stay inside its allowed bounds (< 20) ? I cannot, and the compiler won't check it.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes. `i` will stay until `trouver` equal 1 or `i` equal 20.

Comment: If I read your code correctly, `i` will be incremented beyond recognition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that the problem was in how I search for the minimum starting time in  the machines to start task:

```
....

// Find the minimum time in all machines to start a task
b[3] = b[0]; // this cause the problem
for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count)
{
    if(b[count].t != 0)
        if(b[3].t > b[count + 1].t)
        {
            b[3] = b[count + 1];
        }
}
```

`b[3]` as start could refer to a machine that can't start the current task, so I made a little change:

```
// Find the minimum time in all machines to start a task
            for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count)  // search only in the machines that can execute the current task
            {
                if(b[count].m != -1)
                {
                    b[3] = b[count];
                    break;
                }
            }

            for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count)  // search for the first machines that can execute the current task
            {
                if(b[count].m != -1)
                {
                    if((b[3].t > b[count + 1].t) && (b[count + 1].m != -1)) // make sure the next machine can start the current task
                    {
                        b[3] = b[count + 1];
                    }
                }
            }
```

The complete algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _z_indispo {
    int t1;
    int t2;
} z_indispo; 

typedef struct _machines {
    int t[20]; // array represent time
    z_indispo zone[2];
} machines;

typedef struct _tache {
    int p;
    int w;
    int c; //  p/w
    int i; // Task number
} tache;

typedef struct _bfeet {
    int t; // Store the time to of ending execution by a task
    int m; // The machine responsible for executing a task.
} bfeet;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    machines m[4] = {0};
    tache j[6];
    tache j_tmp;
    bfeet b[4] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int u = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int trouver = 0;
    int f_totale = 0;
    int f[3] = {0};

    m[0].zone[0].t1 = 7;
    m[0].zone[0].t2 = 9;
    m[0].zone[1].t1 = 14;
    m[0].zone[1].t2 = 15;

    m[1].zone[0].t1 = 8;
    m[1].zone[0].t2 = 9;
    m[1].zone[1].t1 = 16;
    m[1].zone[1].t2 = 17;

    m[2].zone[0].t1 = 7;
    m[2].zone[0].t2 = 8;
    m[2].zone[1].t1 = 18;
    m[2].zone[1].t2 = 19;

    /*
     * Initialise all machines
     *   0: Represent free time.
     *  -1: Represent critical zone range.
     *  -2: Represent a task already executed. 
     */
    for(i = 0; i< 3; ++i)
    {
        for(count = 0; count < 20; ++count)
        {
            if((count >= m[i].zone[0].t1 - 1 && count <= m[i].zone[0].t2 - 1) || 
               (count >= m[i].zone[1].t1 - 1 && count <= m[i].zone[1].t2 - 1))
            {
                m[i].t[count] = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                m[i].t[count] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i< 3; ++i)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            printf("   D(1,1)           t1    s1  D(1,2)     t2 s2  D(1,3)\n");
        else if(i == 1)
            printf("   D(2,1)              t1 s1  D(2,2)           t2 s2  D(2,3)\n");
        else if(i == 2)
            printf("   D(3,1)           t1 s1  D(3,2)                    t2 s2  D(3,3)\n");
        printf("|");
        for(count = 0; count < 20; ++count)
        {
                printf("%3d", m[i].t[count]);

        }

        printf(" |\n\n");
    }

    j[0].p = 5;
    j[0].w = 2;
    j[0].i = 1;

    j[1].p = 7;
    j[1].w = 3;
    j[1].i = 2;

    j[2].p = 4;
    j[2].w = 1;
    j[2].i = 3;

    j[3].p = 6;
    j[3].w = 4;
    j[3].i = 4;

    j[4].p = 7;
    j[4].w = 7;
    j[4].i = 5;

    /*
     * Calc C = P/W .
    */
    for(count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
    {
        j[count].c = j[count].p / j[count].w;
    }

    /*
     * Sort tasks from low to hight
     */
    for(count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
    {
        for(k = 0; k < 5 - count; ++k)
        {
            if(j[k].c > j[k + 1].c)
            {
                j_tmp = j[k + 1];
                j[k + 1] = j[k];
                j[k] = j_tmp;
            }
        }
    }


    printf("|%2J  |%2   P  |%2  W  | C  |\n");
    printf("_____________________\n");
    for(count = 0; count < 5; ++count)
    {
        printf("|%-4d|%-4d|%-4d|%-4d|\n", j[count].i, j[count].p, j[count].w, j[count].c);
    }

    printf("\n");

    /*
     * Execute tasks
     */
    while(n < 5) 
    {
        k = 0;
        for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count)
        {
            i = 0;
            u = 0;
            trouver = 0;
            while(i < 20 && trouver != 1)
            {
                if(m[count].t[i] == 0) // we find a free unite
                {
                    while(m[count].t[i] == 0 && u != j[n].p && i < 20) // count a continues free  time, quit when u equal the necessary time to execute the current task
                    {
                        ++u;
                        ++i;
                    }

                    if(u == j[n].p) // we found a free continues time
                    {
                        b[count].t = i - u; // save the starting index
                        b[count].m = count; // save the machine responsible for executing the current task
                        ++k;
                        trouver = 1;
                    }
                    else if(u != j[n].p) // if we encounter zone unavailability or index reserved by another task
                    {
                        u = 0; // restart u counter
                        while((m[count].t[i] == -1 || m[count].t[i] == -2) && (i < 20)) // bypass reserved/unavailability index's
                            ++i;
                    }
                }
                else
                    ++i; // bypass reserved/unavailability index's
            }

            if(trouver != 1) // we mark this machine as it can't execute the current task
            {
                b[count].m = -1;
            }
        }

        if(k == 0)
            printf("There is no free time to execute task %d.\n", j[n].i);
        else
        {
            // Find the minimum time in all machines to start a task
            for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count)  // search only in the machines that can execute the current task
            {
                if(b[count].m != -1)
                {
                    b[3] = b[count];
                    break;
                }
            }

            for(count = 0; count < 3; ++count)  // search only in the machines that can execute the current task
            {
                if(b[count].m != -1)
                {
                    if((b[3].t > b[count + 1].t) && (b[count + 1].m != -1))
                    {
                        b[3] = b[count + 1];
                    }
                }
            }

            // Put -2 to indicate that index as unfree
            u = b[3].t + j[n].p;
            for(count = b[3].t; count < u; ++count)
            {
                m[b[3].m].t[count] = -2;
            }

            if(b[3].m == 0)
                f[0] = f[0] + (b[3].t + j[n].p) * j[n].w;
            else if(b[3].m == 1)
                f[1] = f[1] + (b[3].t + j[n].p) * j[n].w;
            else if(b[3].m == 2)
                f[2] = f[2] + (b[3].t + j[n].p) * j[n].w;

            printf("Task %d end at %-3dms, machine %d.\n", j[n].i, b[3].t + j[n].p, b[3].m + 1);
        }
        ++n;
    }  

    printf("\n"); 
    f_totale = f[0] + f[1] + f[2];
    printf("F of machine 01: %d.\n", f[0]); 
    printf("F of machine 02: %d.\n", f[1]); 
    printf("F of machine 03: %d.\n", f[2]); 
    printf("Total F: %d.\n", f_totale); 
    printf("\n"); 
    printf("\n"); 
    for(i = 0; i< 3; ++i)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            printf("   D(1,1)           t1    s1  D(1,2)     t2 s2  D(1,3)\n");
        else if(i == 1)
            printf("   D(2,1)              t1 s1  D(2,2)           t2 s2  D(2,3)\n");
        else if(i == 2)
            printf("   D(3,1)           t1 s1  D(3,2)                    t2 s2  D(3,3)\n");
        printf("|");
        for(count = 0; count < 20; ++count)
        {
                printf("%3d", m[i].t[count]);

        }

        printf(" |\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have persistent short-by-one errors in your array definitions. Basically, C arrays are zero-indexed, so if you want to access `array[n]`, `array` has to have been defined with size at least `n+1`. For instance your machine struct should be

```
typedef struct _machines {
    int t[20];
    z_indispo zone[2];
} machines;
```

since you access `machine.t[20]` and `machine.zone[1]`.

This fixes the issue in your second update (memory getting stomped on like that is a pretty good indicator that you're indexing beyond the end of the array). The first one will likely get fixed (or at least you'll be a lot further along the road to a solution) once you fix the array initializations in `main()` similarly (e.g. you're accessing `b[3].t`, but since you defined it via `bfeet b[3]` it only has indices `b[0]`, `b[1]` and `b[2]`).